# Selenium java locator strategy to locate radio labels when they don't have tag

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, radio-button, label

I'm able to locate the radios using XPath //form//input[@type='radio'] or using name=gender attribute, however, I'm not sure how to locate the labels of radios since they don't have any label tag.

I tried getText() but return as null. Appreciate your suggestion and option on how to locate labels.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Oftentimes when getText() does not work, using getAttribute("innerHTML") will.